# Header issue in generated TDM via Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, nltk

I'm having some trouble with my Python TDM. Right now it accepts a generated CSV from my other application and then creates a Term Document Matrix out of it. The current issue is that some words in the dictionary that have 0 frequency are still appearing in the header.

[This is the current output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WIjN4.png)
So in this case words like one, simply, focus, money, etc all the way to the right should not be added/displayed at all in the created TDM file.

```py
def termDocumentMatrix():
    # Get filenames of CSV files
    filenames = filedialog.askopenfilename(
        title="Datafluent | Open CSV files for TDM", filetypes=[("Comma Separated Value", "*.csv")]
    )

    # Check file paths
    absolute_path = os.path.dirname(__file__)
    relative_path = "temp/upload/to_tdm"
    folderdir = os.path.join(absolute_path, relative_path)

    # Set new filename for generated CSV
    new_filename = Path(filenames).stem
    new_filename = new_filename.replace(' ', '_')

    # Upload file to temp folder
    try:
        copyfile_tdm(filenames, folderdir)
    except:
        mb.showerror(title="Error!", message="File can't be Opened! Might be Wrong Format or Damaged!")

    # Read raw data from file
    data = pd.read_csv(filenames, header=None)
    tdmfile = data[0].str.cat(sep=' ')

    # Clean data by removing commas and new lines
    tdmfile = tdmfile.replace(",", "")
    tdmfile = tdmfile.replace("\\n", "")

    # Create Lemmatization Object
    lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()

    # Tokenize text into sentences
    tokenizer = sent_tokenize(tdmfile)

    # Lemmatize words to get their proper meaning and remove stop words
    lemmawords = []
    for sentence in tokenizer:
        # Convert non-alphabetic characters to spaces
        sentence = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z]', ' ', sentence)
        tokens = word_tokenize(sentence.lower())
        # Remove stop words and lemmatize remaining words
        lemmawords += [lemmatizer.lemmatize(token) for token in tokens if token not in set(stopwords.words('english'))]

    # Create bag of words dictionary and filter out words with low frequency
    MIN_FREQUENCY = 2
    word_counts = Counter(lemmawords)
    dictionary = {word: i for i, word in enumerate(word_counts.keys()) if word_counts[word] >= MIN_FREQUENCY}

    # Build bag of words model
    sentence_vectors = []
    for sentence in tokenizer:
        sentence_words = set(word_counts.keys()).intersection(set(word_tokenize(sentence)))
        vector = [word_counts[word] for word in sentence_words if word in dictionary]
        sentence_vectors.append(vector)

    sentence_vectors = np.asarray(sentence_vectors)

    # Write output to CSV file
    output_path = f"{new_filename}_TDM.csv"
    with open(output_path, mode='w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as csvfile:
        writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
        header = [word for word in dictionary.keys() if word in set(lemmawords)]
        writer.writerow(header)
        for row in sentence_vectors:
            if not all(x == 0 for x in row):
                writer.writerow(row)

    # Open output file
    os.system(f'start {output_path}')
```

I've tried a couple of fixes but it resulted in things getting a lot worse. I tried building the sentence_vectors and the header_Words together but no luck. I tried adjusting the header but no luck as well.

Comment: Can you provide an example of csv file?

Comment: Yes hello. This is the one we're currently using. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1efbxeNmiE0nAgvues3hIJ1hSRbEkQwRG/view?usp=sharing

Comment: What should be the expected output?

Comment: Hello, the expected output is the one I linked in the post. There is a header full of words across the row and the columns have different word counts. However right now the current output also has words that have no frequency in their columns. Like say the word simply or money. What can we do to remove the words that do not occur and therefore shouldn't be in the output? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
# Tokenize text into sentences
tokenizer = sent_tokenize(tdmfile)

# New code from here
MIN_FREQUENCY = 2
stop_words = stopwords.words('english')

bags = []
for sentence in tokenizer:
    sentence = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z]', ' ', sentence)
    tokens = [lemmatizer.lemmatize(token)
                  for token in word_tokenize(sentence.lower())
                  if token not in stop_words]
    bags.append(Counter(tokens))

bags = pd.DataFrame(bags).fillna(0).astype(int)
bags = bags.loc[: , bags.sum() > MIN_FREQUENCY]

# Export to file
bags.replace(0, '').to_csv(f'{new_filename}_TDM.csv', index=False)
```

Output:

```
>>> bags
     document  entrepreneur  businessman  choose  ten  make  given  answer  ...  attack  company  trick  cybercriminals  personal  vulnerable  sensitive  apps
0           1             2            1       1    1     1      1       1  ...       0        0      0               0         0           0          0     0
1           0             0            0       0    0     0      0       0  ...       0        0      0               0         0           0          0     0
2           0             1            1       0    0     0      0       0  ...       0        0      0               0         0           0          0     0
3           0             0            0       0    0     0      0       0  ...       0        0      0               0         0           0          0     0
4           0             0            0       0    0     1      0       0  ...       0        0      0               0         0           0          0     0
..        ...           ...          ...     ...  ...   ...    ...     ...  ...     ...      ...    ...             ...       ...         ...        ...   ...
267         0             0            0       0    0     0      0       0  ...       0        0      0               0         0           0          0     0
268         0             0            0       0    0     0      0       0  ...       0        0      0               0         0           0          0     0
269         0             0            0       0    0     0      0       0  ...       0        0      0               0         0           0          1     0
270         0             0            0       0    0     0      0       0  ...       0        0      0               0         0           0          0     1
271         0             0            0       0    0     0      0       0  ...       0        0      0               0         0           0          0     0

[272 rows x 337 columns]
```

Comment: Oh this looks interesting. Sorry, I will have to clarify though the goal. 


The desired output is that 0s should not display at all (possibly left blank like in the old output), instead should a word has all 0s for example, like (attack, company, trick) they will not be present in the output file at all. And if a word has a few instances of 0 but has some otherwise, only the non-zero ones are displayed.

Comment: Words like 'attack', 'company', 'trick' appear at least 3 times (understand they appear at least in 3 sentences). All word appears less 3 times have been removed. However, you have some sentences with no token (row contains only 0)

Comment: Check the output of the csv file now. All 0s have been removed.